# Do I need to abbreviate plurals separately or can I just add an 's' at the end of original abbreviation?

Tags: abbreviations, acronyms

I am writing an abstract for an article. I am using abbreviation Road Traffic Accident (RTA).

In the further sentences I need to use plural of RTA that is  Road Traffic Accidents (RTAs).

My question is, can I directly write RTAs when I need to use plural of RTA or should I abbreviate Road Traffic Accidents (RTAs) first then use its abbreviation.

Answer (score 1):

If the acronym RTA with its expansion has come at least once before, one can use 'RTAs' as plural.